# Create Bagnet on Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, patch

I am currently trying to implement a Bagnet on keras following this article :https://www.lyrn.ai/2019/02/14/bagnet-imagenet-with-a-simple-bof-model/
I am building one model to evaluate a patch and another to evaluate the averaging of all my patchs. And I try to ensemble them with an input: (number of patchs,x_patch,y_patch,channel_patch). But it isnt working well. My main issues come from evaluating all of the patchs and average the result.
Here is my code. If anyone has suggestion on how to deal with that.

```
def build_patch_model(lr, l2,patch_number):

##############
# BRANCH MODEL
##############
regul  = regularizers.l2(l2)
optim  = Adam(lr=lr)
kwargs = {'padding':'same', 'kernel_regularizer':regul}

inp = Input(shape=patch_size) # patch qxqx3

#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(inp) # 24x24x128
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(inp)
for _ in range(6): x = subblock(x, 32, **kwargs)

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x) # 24x24x128
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(x)
for _ in range(6): x = subblock(x, 64, **kwargs)

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x) # 24x24x128
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(x)
for _ in range(6): x = subblock(x, 128, **kwargs) 

#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x) # 24x24x128
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(x)
for _ in range(6): x = subblock(x, 256, **kwargs)

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x) # 24x24x128
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(x)
for _ in range(6): x = subblock(x, 512, **kwargs)

#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x) # 24x24x128
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(1080, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(x)
for _ in range(6): x = subblock(x, 1080, **kwargs)


x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x) # 24x24x128
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(2048, (1,1), activation='relu', **kwargs)(x) 
for _ in range(12): x = subblock(x, 2048, **kwargs)


x       = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x) # 2048

y       = Dense(5004, use_bias=False, activation="softmax", name='patch_heatmap')(x)

branch_model      = Model(inp, y)

branch_model.compile(optim, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_crossentropy', 'acc'])

return branch_model




build_averaging_model():

##############
# HEAD MODEL #
##############

#x = Average()(input_head)
inp = Input(shape=(5004,))
x = Dense(5004,use_bias=False, activation="softmax", name='patch_sum')(inp)

head_model = Model(inp, x, name='head')

#x = head_model([xa, xb])

return head_model


def build_model(head_model,branch_model):

inp = Input(shape=(patch_number,patch_size[0],patch_size[1],patch_size[2]))

input_head = []

for i in range(patch_number):
    input_head.append(branch_model(inp[i,:,:,:]))


x = Average()(input_head)

x = head_model(x)

model = Model(inp,x)

return model
```